# How to get rid of "document overhead" from PDF file?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp (`iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper`) to add thousands of link to an existing PDF file to create a new file.
The problem is that the created file is huge (for example, original size is 20m, but the created file size is 500m). I analyzed it with Acrobat Pro, it shows 90% of that file was occupied by "document overhead". I don't know what it is, nor why iTextSharp includes that in the file.

Is it possible to make iTextSharp create the new file without "document overhead"? or how can I get rid of the "document overhead" from the PDF file?

Comment: Can you provide a short example of code that shows this? Also, what version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm using iTextSharp 4.5.5.0

Comment: Are you sure of that version number? 4.1.6 was the last official version before jumping to 5.

Comment: Very sorry about that, I'm using iTextSharp 5.4.5.0

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF with overhead? (Maybe not the 500MB file, though...) And can you post the pivotal code?